# How can I host a LAN server on an Android device?

Tags: java, android

I want to know if there is a way to host a LAN server on Android without using a third party library.

I want the solution to work without rooting the device.

Comment: This question contains many other topics and nearly none of them are related to java.

Comment: What is a lan server?

Comment: @greenapps a server that only can be accessed through the local network. LucasB: Use sockets and server sockets, look into using a server basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a way to host a LAN server on Android without using a third party library.

It is possible. You have to use Sockets and ServerSockets, Object[Input/Output]Stream(or a different way to send data). Basically design a server.

[Here is an SO post on creating a server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2187626/6296561)

[Here is the Java documentation on servers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#server)

You can use third party libraries to make servers too(see the first link), and sometimes that may be easier.

Comment: Those two links don't address the need for the Asynctask on Android to do any network operation, though

Comment: Those links are meant as a basic pointer. AsyncTask is a requirement for internet connections, but using sockets and serversockets in combination with it is the key and core of a server

Comment: So, the answer is "yes, but it's tricky and complicated, and using a library would be easier"? ;)

Comment: It is tricky and complicated, yes (But it is java, what isn't? Everything throws exceptions if set up incorrectly). Libraries **may** make it easier. It depends on what the server is being used for, and the capabilities of the libraries. Making it from the ground (if done correctly) it may make a very good server. Using a library is a shortcut because you don't have to write as much code(the library may contain most of the framework). So basically, the answer is "yes, but it's tricky, but using a library may make it easier"